# Qt Creator in Emacs keybind

Tags: qt, emacs, qt-creator

Any way to realize `emacs` keybind on `Qt Creator` (QTC)?

Some possibilities:

- [`emacskeys`](https://github.com/fberger/emacskeys/blob/master/README.markdown)  but I failed to build (maybe because version supported by `emacskeys` is QTC 2.2.1 as of today).
- [Utilizing `FakeVim` feature](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-creator/2009-April/002832.html) (I haven't tried b/c modifying `vim` keybind and adjusting to that of `emacs` seems complicate)
- [Associating `emacsclient`](http://linux.amazingdev.com/blog/archives/000932.html) (not tried)

Build error with `emacskeys`:

```
user@host:/usr/share/qtcreator/qt-creator-2.5.0-src$ sudo /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin/qmake && make
cd src/ && /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.2/bin/qmake /usr/share/qtcreator/qt-creator-2.5.0-src/src/src.pro -o Makefile
Failure to open file: /usr/share/qtcreator/qt-creator-2.5.0-src/src/Makefile
Unable to generate makefile for: /usr/share/qtcreator/qt-creator-2.5.0-src/src/src.pro
make: *** [src/Makefile] Error 5
```

Environment) `Ubuntu` 10.04, `Qt` 4.8.2, `Qt` 2.5

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inspired by [this comment](https://github.com/fberger/emacskeys/issues/4#issuecomment-5137590), I've managed to configure `emacs` keybind, using `QTC`'s feature.

1. "Environment" -> "Keyboard" tab
2. Download config file from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/lateeye/emacsKeyMap_QtCreator-2.5_12Jun11.kms?attredirects=0&d=1)
3. Import it.

Note that I've only included simple text editor commands (e.g. C-a, C-e etc.).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Remark: Some of these keybindings cause conflicts, which QtCreator (2.7.0) does not report. For example, Ctrl+A did not work for me because of this. I had to search the key bindings list for occurrences of Ctrl+A and manually remove the conflicting ones.